# PowerShell and RegEx: match whole line except space and empty lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm still having problems with the understanding of RegEx.

I have a Textbox in Powershell which is supposed to receive several Groups of a domain.
like:

```
G-ITDep-Location-RWXD
G-R-ITHR-666-42-All-RWXD

G-R-ITHR-666-42-All-EndUsers
 SP-P-TKDep-ISIS-Member 
Domain Users
```

With the input I want to get the groupmembers of each group via Get-ADGroupMember. However, with my current regex, I can only capture every single line.
While this is ok for myself, I have to think about my colleges and possible errors. In case of my example above, there is one empty line and a "space" at the beginning and end of another line.
So how do I filter out empty lines and leading/ending whitespace characters?

Here's what I have:

```
$Groups = [regex]::Matches($textboxUseradminInput.Text, '(?mi)^(.*)$')
foreach ($do in $Groups)
            {
                $richtextboxgetGroupsGrpMembers.Text += "$do" + ":`n"
                $richtextboxgetGroupsGrpMembers.Text += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$do" -Server "192.168.3.99" |`
                foreach { $_.Name } | Out-String
}
```

Comment: Do you still want to match the line with leading/trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will filter out any trailing or starting white space.

```
 ([^\s].+[^\s])
```

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vJ8tI4/1).

make sure that your regex can handle multilines.

Comment: alright thanks. the negation stuff is new to me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean it up post-regex, you can filter out empty lines with a where or if clause and strip whitespace by using String::Trim()

```
$inputText | % { if ($_) { $_.Trim() } } | Out-String
```

Comment: that's also a good idea. But as I try to learn regex, I prefer to do as much as possible in regex :-)